# How to check a program run successful in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have to run some programs in bash script.Sometimes program may not give result.

```
#!/bin/sh
for k in $( seq 1 20)
do
echo -n ${k}' ' >> 2.txt
./s${k}>>2.txt & sleep 5
done
```

My ideal result like this:

```
1 result001
2 result002
3 
4 result004
```

But after run my code,the result is

```
1 result001
2 result002
3 4 result004
```

So my problem is how to check a program run successful in bash script?Thank you!

Comment: If you want sequential results you'll have to run the scripts sequentially. Why `&`?

Comment: @Biffen Because some programs may be deadlock so i need `& sleep 5` to comfirm the script can run as normal.Thank you.

Comment: You can't get sequential output from processes running in parallel without manually collecting (and sequencing) the output. How do you "confirm the script can run as normal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
 #!/bin/bash


    for k in {1..20}
    do
       result=$(./s${k} & sleep 5)
       printf "%b %b\n" $k $result >> 2.txt
    done
```

The following output was given when testing this script:

```
1 result1
2 result2
3 
4 result4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `wait`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28command%29

> wait [n]
>
> where n is the pid or job ID of a currently executing background
>   process (job). If n is not given, the command waits until all jobs
>   known to the invoking shell have terminated.
>
> wait normally returns the exit status of the last job which
>   terminated. It may also return 127 in the event that n specifies a
>   non-existent job or zero if there were no jobs to wait for.
>
> Because wait needs to be aware of the job table of the current shell
>   execution environment, it is usually implemented as a shell builtin.

Just add `wait` after this line

```
./s${k}>>2.txt & sleep 5
wait
```

In case the process can deadlock - another option is `timeout`

```
timeout -s 9 5 ./s${k}>>2.txt # Waits 5 seconds and then kill the process
```

Comment: If the job deadlocks, this will wait infinitely.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelJaros, didn't noticed that it could be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the jobs sequentially and use [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) to limit execution time:

```
#!/bin/sh
for k in $( seq 1 20)
do
  echo -n ${k}' ' >> 2.txt
  timeout -k 8 5 ./s${k}>>2.txt
done
```

This will terminate each job with the `TERM` signal (allowing cleanup via signal handlers to run) after 5 seconds and, if unsuccessful, with the `KILL` signal after 8 seconds.

However from your shell's perspective, no parallel processes are involved and you don't need to solve any concurrency problems.